# Orderby atributo de campo relacionado Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, datatables, eloquent

requiero de su importante asesoramiento para realizar la tarea de ordenar my tabla por fecha de vencimiento de los productos.

Pasa lo siguiente la fecha de vencimiento proviene de los lotes, un producto tiene varios lotes, pero un lote pertenece a un solo producto, es una realición de uno a muchos, pasa que en la tabla, que esta realizada con data table con serve-side, muestro ese campo la fecha de vencimiento del lote de ese producto proximo a vencer (img 1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces requiero organizar la tabla en orden a la fecha de vencimiento.

he intentado lo siguiente pero no me da.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien intente enviando un array ordenado previamente pero tampoco ha funcionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sigue sin enviarme los datos de forma ordenada por la fecha de vencimiento, asi que necesito de su asesoramiento a ver si estoy haciendo algo mal, muchas gracias

Comment: hola, no tabajamos con codigo en imagenes, por favor usa texto para el codigo siempre, otra cosa no se supone que debe ir todo en un solo query builder???